# Tracing unexpected changes in matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a large matrix (9600x9600, 703.6 Mb) that keeps changing for no apparent reason. When created it looks fine, but after being used for calculations all of the sudden all the values except for a few columns are replaced by 0s. It's driving me a bit crazy since I cannot debug the problem. Is there a way to trace what is making this variable change? Like a change or access log? Or alternatively is there a way to lock the variable so that it cannot be modified?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

edit:

It seems matrix "L" is modified after applying this equation, even after it has been locked through 'lockBinding':

```
F.calc.E = function(M,p){
  M$V1 <- paste(M$V1,M$V2,sep = ", ")
  p.loc = grep(pattern = p,x = M$V1) # loc of target pressure
  p.vector = as.numeric(M[p.loc,4:ncol(M),with=FALSE])
  pL = mmult(L,p.vector)
  return(pL)
}
```

The code for the mmult function is this, obtained through another SO post:

```
func <- 'NumericMatrix mmult( NumericMatrix m , NumericVector v , bool byrow = true ){
if( byrow );
if( ! m.nrow() == v.size() ) stop("Non-conformable arrays") ;
if( ! byrow );
if( ! m.ncol() == v.size() ) stop("Non-conformable arrays") ;

NumericMatrix out(m) ;

if( byrow ){
for (int j = 0; j < m.ncol(); j++) {
for (int i = 0; i < m.nrow(); i++) {
out(i,j) = m(i,j) * v[j];
}
}
}
if( ! byrow ){
for (int i = 0; i < m.nrow(); i++) {
for (int j = 0; j < m.ncol(); j++) {
out(i,j) = m(i,j) * v[i];
}
}
}
return out ;
}'
```

I am still unable to debug.

Comment: My suggestion would be to maintain a copy of the original status of your matrix. Then after each calculation compare the matrix to the copy - this will help you identify the point at which it is changing.

Comment: @JamesElderfield I don't think it would be feasible enough for a **703.6 Mb** matrix

Comment: If you need additional help, post your code: a sample (smaller) matrix along with the calculations. It is not possible to diagnose your problem without being able to replicate it.

Comment: @KunalPuri Is it always the same columns that get set to 0? Just check one of those columns (or a small part) against the copy.

Comment: @Imo please see edit

Answer (score 2):

You could use `lockBinding`:

```
m <- matrix(1:4, 2)
evil.fun <- function(x) .GlobalEnv[[x]][2,2] <- 0
evil.fun("m")
m
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    3
#[2,]    2    0

m <- matrix(1:4, 2)
lockBinding("m", .GlobalEnv)
evil.fun("m")
#Error in .GlobalEnv[[x]][2, 2] <- 0 : 
#  cannot change value of locked binding for 'm'

unlockBinding("m", .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it did not work but I did not know this function. Please see the edit. The variable keeps changing even after it has been locked.

Comment: `NumericMatrix mmult( const NumericMatrix m , ...` or use `clone`.

Comment: Tried 'const' but did not work. Tried 'clone' but I was unable to make it work as I am completely unfamiliar with C++ writing...